# can I upgrade a 2012 MBPr SSD with a modern SSD NVMe using an adapter

Tags: ssd, upgrade, sata

I want to upgrade the SSD stick in a 2012 MBPr from the m.SATA to a more modern NVMe.  I know the speed will be the same (6GB), but my plan is to remove the NVMe drive and use it elsewhere later.  I see buying a m.SATA drive being a waste.

Can I use an adapter to run a modern SSD card in an old mid-2012 MBPr that was made for SATA?

Comment: What’s the point?  It’s a SATA III connection and you won’t see any performance benefit. If you already own the components that’s one thing, but if buying new, just get a 2.5” SATA SSD

Comment: The 2.5" form factor doesn't fit this MBP.  It only has the stick type, I think called m.SATA.  The point isn't a speed upgrade, the point is a size upgrade and to be able to use the drive in a later build.

Comment: If memory serves, a 2012 used a proprietary interface, but there were adapters.  I don’t recall how reliable they were.  The standard MBP used regular SATA.  I missed the “Retina” in your question

Comment: Yes, Apple used a proprietary interface and I'm wondering if those adapters allow for NVMe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this excellent 'history' of SSDs in Macs:

https://beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd-ultimate-guide-to-specs-and-upgrades

NVMe was only supported in Macs with "Generation 3" SSDs - dating from 2013 onward.

Your Mac can't support NVMe. It's unlikely that an adaptor would support it independently.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments/review for one of those small adapters I found the user who said that he used that adapter with Macbook Pro Retina 2012 and it worked (with NVMe). Probably there are more people to confirm.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]